# Not able to accept android licenses while running flutter doctor

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and have been trying to accept the android licenses but there's an error which I attached down below.

```
C:\Users\Sharav>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Error: Could not find or load main class Sharav\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\\..
```

Comment: Did you add flutter sdk to environment variables or you try running the same command in the flutter sdk folder

Comment: I added flutter sdk to environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure :

- Downloaded Android SDK and installed correctly
- you Have added your flutter SDK to the environment variables
- try to run the command again in your SDK folder